# How to differentiate between different http requests by how they are initiated

Tags: networking, network-programming, httpwebrequest, http-headers, network-protocols

I am working on a networking program that monitors network traffic. I would like to separate all http requests based on how they are initiated. I am considering the following four types of request.

1. a http request initiated by user entering the url in the web browser
2. a http request that is triggered by a user clicking a link on the web page
3. a http request automatically triggered by a resource within a fetched page. For example, if there is a img in the page, it will trigger another request.
4. AJAX updates

For 1 vs others, I am thinking about using the referer header.

For 4 vs others, I am thinking about using the X-Requested-With header.

But I can't think of a way to differentiate between 2 and 3.

Any idea if it is possible to tell the difference between 2 and 3? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would passing a parameter as part of the request be acceptable?  That would allow you to differentiate between 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks, user91208. Unfortunately, no, the source of the requests is a commercial browser which we have not control over.

Answer (score 0):

A request for a resource should use the source page as the referrer header. So, it could be similar to #2 but being smart with looking back at previously requested URLs for the appropriate page, and reclassifying those new URLs as page resources.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. The problem is that the resource may not be located at the same URL (base) as the referer. For example, the orginital request URL is www.foo.com, but it can embedded an img from www.bar.com. Unless I do a parsing of the previous response to see if it contains the link. Is that what you were suggestion? I hope there is a simpler solution than parsing response and keeping track of all the href's.